# How to insert a struct into a set and print the members of the set?

Tags: c++, struct, insert, set

I have to use the struct mov

```
struct mov {
   string src;
   string dst;
};
```

where src is the source and dst is the destination. The purpose of the program is to analyze the pieces on a chessboard and generate all of the possible moves. The possible moves must be represented in a set but it must be a set of moves, so set. I've found some methods saying to implement a comparator but I have no clue if it works because when printing the set (using an iterator) I get errors because of the "<<" when printing I guess its conflicting with the comparator since it uses "<"???

Comment: `<<` and `<` are two totally separate operators, and C++ won't ever confuse them.  You might, but the compiler won't.

Comment: Usually there are no conflicts for a compiler regarding distinguishing `operator<()` from `operator<<()`, you problem seems to be about some different issue. Would you mind to show a [MCVE] reproducing your exact problem please?

Answer (score 2):

`<<` and `<` are never confused. Packing `mov` members and using the fact that `std::tuple` implements `operator<` as a lexicographical ordering, you can easily write a comparator of `mov` as follows:

```
struct mov 
{  
    std::string src; 
    std::string dst;

    bool operator<(const mov& rhs) const {
        return std::tie(src, dst) < std::tie(rhs.src, rhs.dst);
    }
};
```

Then this works with `std::set` as follows. [**DEMO is here.**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GFanMAKYNwT5nxpG)

```
int main()
{
    std::set<mov> moves{ {"src1","dts1"}, {"src2","dts2"}, {"src3","dts3"} };

    // iterator
    std::cout << "Using iterator," << std::endl;
    for(auto it = moves.begin(); it != moves.cend(); ++it){
        std::cout << it->src << "," << it->dst << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;    

    // range-based-for
    std::cout << "Using range-based-for," << std::endl;
    for(const auto& mov_i : moves){
        std::cout << mov_i.src << "," << mov_i.dst << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```